# Append data to an existing excel spreadsheet

Tags: python, excel

I wrote the following function to accomplish this task.

```
def write_file(url,count):

    book = xlwt.Workbook(encoding="utf-8")
    sheet1 = book.add_sheet("Python Sheet 1")
    colx = 1
    for rowx in range(1):

        # Write the data to rox, column
        sheet1.write(rowx,colx, url)
        sheet1.write(rowx,colx+1, count)


    book.save("D:\Komal\MyPrograms\python_spreadsheet.xls")
```

For every url taken from a given .txt file, I want to be able to count the number of tags and print that to each excel file.  I want to overwrite the file for each url, and then append to the excel file.

Answer (score 6):

You should use `xlrd.open_workbook()` for loading the existing Excel file, create a writeable copy using `xlutils.copy`, then do all the changes and save it as.

Something like that:

```
from xlutils.copy import copy    
from xlrd import open_workbook

book_ro = open_workbook("D:\Komal\MyPrograms\python_spreadsheet.xls")
book = copy(book_ro)  # creates a writeable copy
sheet1 = book.get_sheet(0)  # get a first sheet

colx = 1
for rowx in range(1):
    # Write the data to rox, column
    sheet1.write(rowx,colx, url)
    sheet1.write(rowx,colx+1, count)

book.save("D:\Komal\MyPrograms\python_spreadsheet.xls")
```

Comment: @komalbhardwaj sorry, I fixed it. It's the `book` object.

Comment: NameError: global name 'wb' is not defined

Comment: @komalbhardwaj `sheet1 = book.get_sheet(0)`, check the fixed code above

Comment: Note that during copying, some data may be lost. Such as some formula, which means in certain situation you just cannot append data to an existing excel using xlrd/xlwt/xlutils.