# Inserting excel sheet as an input

Tags: python-3.x, excel

i have a excel sheet  **(Dictionary)** of 10 rows by 2 columns containing ** to write a python code** respectively. Now i want to write a code so that i can insert another Excel Sheet as an Input containing only 5 names (5 rows and only 1 column) and these names are randomly chosen from that Dictionary. as the input are only in 1 column so i want the output or result ***Jobs*** to be printed besides to that input column!
N:B: The result ***Jobs*** should be matched from the Dictionary in according to the Input which was randomly picked from the Dictionary.

Can someone please help me or to give an idea to write a python code? I would also appreciate if somebody atleast can suggest me the concept how i should proceed on!

Comment: This is a lot of questions at the same time... you need to decompose your problem into smaller tasks and then learn how to implement them one by one. Start by reading about and learning how to read and insert excel files and sheets using python. Then after having some code working come back and ask specific questions about issues you have.

Comment: okay thank you :) @pedro Ferreira

Comment: Looking forward to your next questions ;-) This other question might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38081658/adding-a-sheet-to-an-existing-excel-worksheet-without-deleting-other-sheet

Comment: Or this other one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28363562/append-data-to-an-existing-excel-spreadsheet